# Precision of Fortran vs that of Matlab

Tags: matlab, floating-point, fortran, precision

In Fortran, I output the result of `tanh(1)` and I get the value `0.7615941763`:

```
open(unit=2, file='test_digits.txt', ACTION="write")
write(2, '(1000F14.10)')( real(tanh(1.0)))
```

However, I now try to do the same in MatLAB and the output is `0.761594155955765`. There is a difference at the 8th digit.

What is the reason for this precision-difference? Can I fix it somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matlab is using double precision by default, you are using single precision floats! They are limited to 7-8 digits... If you use double precision as well, you will get the same precision:

```
program test
  write(*,*) 'single precision:', tanh(1.0)
  write(*,*) 'double precision:', tanh(1.0d0)
end program
```

Output:

```
 single precision:  0.761594176    
 double precision:  0.76159415595576485
```